# Accessing a method on a Backbone.js view inside of loop

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on an app that has an `ItemListView` that contains a number of `ItemView` elements. In my `ItemListView`, I'm using the jQuery `.each()` method to loop through the collection of items and render them as list elements.

I've got all the pieces in place except for the actual attaching of the `li` elements to the containing `ul`. The sticking point is getting access to the `ItemListView.appendItem` method from inside of my `.each()` loop. I've tried using `this.appendItem` and `self.appendItem`, but inside the loop `this` is the `item` and `self` is the `window` object.

Here's what I have right now:

```
ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#item-rows',
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new Items();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        $.each(this.collection.models, function (i, item) {
            var itemview = new ItemView( { model: item });
            this.appendItem(itemview); // this refers to the item, so appendItem is undefined
        });
    },
    appendItem: function (itemView) {
        $(this.el).append(itemView.render().el);
    }
});

var itemlistview = new ItemListView;
```

I'm pretty sure that the context issue is the only problem, as I've examined the other pieces of the this by outputting them to the console and they look fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's a pretty simple fix.  You just gotta refer to the `this` in the outer context.

```
render: function () {
    var somereftothis = this;
    $.each(this.collection.models, function (i, item) {
        var itemview = new ItemView( { model: item });
        somereftothis.appendItem(itemview); // this refers to the item, so appendItem is undefined
    });
},
```

Comment: It is common practive to call that temporary variable "that".

Comment: And yet better practice to set the context correctly as in the answer posted by @rfunduk

Answer (score 3):

A more Backbone-y way to do this would be to use the collection's `each`, provided by underscore.js:

```
render: function() {
  this.collection.each( function( item, index ) {
    var itemView = new ItemView( { model:item } );
    this.appendItem( itemView );
  }, this );
  return this;
}
```

Notes:

- notice the second param to `each` which take a reference to bind the function to
- the [`each`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each) takes the element first and the index second
- `render` should generally return `this` for chaining purposes (as mentioned in the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render)), I don't think your `appendItem` function will work as you expect without this part